# Using SSL with Android App

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm following [this](http://blog.callistaenterprise.se/2011/11/24/android-tlsssl-mutual-authentication/) tutorial to implement https connection between an Android  App and my server.

I have  some problems:

- *Keystore* and *getKeystorePassword* are not identificated like metod.
- *createSSLSocketFactory()* has not parameters but it's defined like *createSSLSocketFactory(final Context context)*.
- I don't undersand if the class "*public class SecureHttpClient
  extends DefaultHttpClient*" finishes before *@override
  clientConnectionManager* and if the code writen in the **Using the Secure Client** section has to be inserted in my mainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

The function you have to use,,

```
/******************************for https request***********************************************/
    private HttpClient sslClient(HttpClient client) {
        try {
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() { 
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(getString(R.string.tls));
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
            SSLSocketFactory ssf = new MySSLSocketFactory(ctx);
            ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = client.getConnectionManager();
            SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
            sr.register(new Scheme(getString(R.string.https), ssf, 443));
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, client.getParams());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(getString(R.string.tls));

        public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(truststore);

            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        }

        public MySSLSocketFactory(SSLContext context) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(null);
            sslContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        }
    }
    /**********************************end********************************************/
```

And U have to call the above mentioned function like described below,,,,

```
// Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();




 //The Line you need to use to call above function
        HttpClient sslHttpsClient=sslClient(client);




HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(sslHttpsClient.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
        HttpResponse response;
```